# Homeowners Association with old homes in it, tiny fees?

Tags: real-estate

Normally, I associate homeowner associations with newer developments, gated communities and fees in the hundreds of dollars.

In house shopping, however, I occasionally see HOAs that are not like this at all. This have a small collection of random old homes in them, often in expensive neighborhoods. By "old" I mean houses built before 1930. The fees for these HOAs are usually tiny. For example, I have seen some with houses that cost $2 million and the HOA fee is literally $17 per month. These HOAs are not "gated communities". They are just random houses sitting right next to other houses that are not in the HOA.

What is the idea behind such trusts or associations? Is it possible to pull a house out of a trust like this after buying it?

Comment: Your idea of HOA's was just a bit narrow, some only exist to enforce neighborhood standards, some take care of landscaping/snow removal, and all exterior upkeep. The important thing is to evaluate the HOA's services and financials as part of the buying process, because some are a mess.

Answer (score 5):

Older neighborhoods were once new neighborhoods and they had quite active HOAs then. There was often little need for HOAs once all the houses had been built and the landscaping done because there were few covenants left to be enforced, and little maintenance to be done: no grassy common areas to be kept mowed and weeded, gates or entryways to be maintained, etc. I lived for twenty years in such an older neighborhood and the only time the HOA did anything was when a new person bought a house in the subdivision and began parking an enormous RV in his driveway. So, yes, $17 per month could even be considered an exorbitant HOA fee in some older neighborhoods; I think mine was more like $30 per *year* (in a neighborhood with about 50 houses). In a new neighborhood (and especially gated communities), HOA fees are of course much larger.

with regard to taking a house *out* of a HOA, it might not be possible at all. Generally, HOA covenants are considered to be *covenants running with the land* meaning that you agree to them as a precondition of purchasing the property (land), and they can be removed only by unanimous consent of all the HOA members (or be struck down by the courts e.g. covenants prohibiting sale to non-Caucasians or to members of other religious faiths). Note that the HOA *Board* cannot waive the covenants for you; it needs the written consent of all the HOA members. Of course, the HOA Board in an older neighborhood might not *enforce* the covenants against you if you violate them; unless some HOA members insist that the covenants still bind everyone and the Board better enforce them. That is what happened with the RV guy mentioned in the previous paragraph; the immediate neighbors complained to the Board whereas I didn't even know about the issue (on a different street) until contacted by one of the complainants.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest driver for monthly cost is the number of shared amenities.

If there are townhouses or condos in the HOA the shared costs of the parking lot and private road have to be split among all the homeowners through the HOA. There are also shared building costs. These items have annual costs for maintenance and snow removal and also replacement costs that must be budgeted for.

If the community has a large amount of community property that also has some costs for mowing and landscaping.

But the biggest costs can be for the pools, tennis courts, basketball courts, gyms, and clubhouse. All have maintenance costs, and capital costs. They may require lifeguards and other employees.

In my community the HOA fee is $70 a year. But the pool, which is optional, adds $200-$500 a year based on the size of the family. The townhouse units pay another couple of hundred a year to pay for their common grounds and structures.

Some in our community have said that we need a professional manager instead of a volunteer run HOA. But that would raise the dues by $100 a year. That proposal hasn't made much progress when people realize most of the HOA funds would go to pay the management company, and the biggest job they would have is sending out bills and chasing down delinquent payments, which would go up as the dues increase.

Getting out of HOA is almost impossible. It would, depending on the state laws, take almost unanimous vote of the entire community to modify the required documents. The HOA is linked to the property records filed with the state and local government. It is virtually impossible to claim you were not aware, because you will sign paperwork related to the HOA several times during the home buying process.

It is possible it is dormant, but that doesn't mean that somebody in the future will cause it to be reactivated. I know of an HOA that after 20+ years of not enforcing many of their rules is trying to now enforce them. It is a headache for everybody. Every fence is in violation, but some fences are brand new and some have been in place for decades. Everybody flagged is threatening to sue, as is everybody who thinks more should be flagged..

If you don't want to live in a HOA, don't buy in an HOA.